# How to write only new text to a text file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm tring to write a C++ application that will only write new text that that is not already contained in a text file, but so far I can't get my implementation won't work. Text is written into the text file even where the text is already contained.

What could I be doing wrong?

The following is my implementation so far.

```
void ScanDir::qDirIteratorScanner()
{
    QDirIterator it(this -> basePath, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        paths = scanned();

        qDebug() << "Collected : " << paths.size();

        if (!paths.contains(it.next())) {
            WriteToFile writeToFile(basePath, it.next());
            paths << it.next();
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "Already put : " << it.next();
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
QStringList ScanDir::scanned()
{
    QStringList paths;

    QFile dataFile(basePath + "data.txt");
    QTextStream in (&dataFile);

    if (dataFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&dataFile);

        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            paths << line;
        }

        dataFile.close();
    }

    return paths;
}
```

---

```
WriteToFile::WriteToFile(QString path, QString data)
{
    path = "E:/Data.txt";
    QFile file(path);
    if ( file.open(QFile::Append) )
    {
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << data << endl;
        qDebug() << "Writting: " << data + "\r\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: Does scanned() return what you think it should?

Comment: Yes it does work, perfectly @UKMonkey .

Comment: Well, if your `paths` is what you expect it to be, then either it.next() isn't what you think it is, or paths.contains doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: You have `QTextStream in(&dataFile);` twice in your `scanned` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call it.next() once per iteration:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#next

> Advances the iterator to the next entry, and returns the file path of
>   this new entry. If hasNext() returns false, this function does
>   nothing, and returns an empty QString.
>
> You can call fileName() or filePath() to get the current entry file
>   name or path, or fileInfo() to get a QFileInfo for the current entry.

Comment: Thank you @Hans Olsson. That was where I was going wrong.